# Openwhisk Editor renaming a sequence produces duplicates

Tags: ibm-cloud, openwhisk

If I click on rename for a particular sequence in the Bluemix Editor, it will create a new sequence with the name, but the "old" sequence does still exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks very much for the bug report. We have replicated this issue: under certain conditions, the rename fails to delete the old sequence. We'll get this fixed as soon as possible!

In the time being, a workaround is to manually delete the sequence with the old name. There will be no harm in doing so.

Nick Mitchell
IBM OpenWhisk Team